# Backup data files in LocalState folder before uninstall Windows Store apps

Tags: microsoft-metro, uninstallation

I've developed a Windows Store apps and save some data in SQLite, and the data file is in LocalState folder. 
I know for the OS policy when I uninstall the app from windows, the appdata folder will delete automatically.

**My question is
1. Is there any idea to deny user uninstall some specified Windows Store apps that I developed from windows?**

*If I can do it, I think can develop a Windows Program to install & uninstall Windows Store apps by using Powershell, and I can backup the LocalState data by C# code.*

**2. If No.1 is impossible, can I catch the uninstall action from Windows?**

*I think I can develop a Windows Service and set it to Auto Run when windows startup, and if I can catch the uninstall action from Windows by using the Windows Service that I developed, I can backup the data by C# code in Windows Service.* 
Is there anybody who can help me out?
Thanks.